# How to remove door panel from Bosch dishwasher with buttons on top?

Tags: dishwasher

I have a Bosch dishwasher with buttons on top (SHP65T55UC) and am trying to remove the front panel from the door.

I've found several guides that all appear to say the same thing about Bosch dishwashers:

- Open the door
- Using a TORX bit, remove the 6 (or 8) screws on the side of the door (not the screws at the top which hold the control panel in
- Close the door completely
- Pull the bottom of the panel away from the unit.
- With the bottom pulled away, pull down on the panel to remove.

When I do that, the panel still seems to hold on somewhere.  It's not attached to the top panel, but pulling on it deforms the top panel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After nearly breaking the door thinking something was stuck, I finally noticed that the inside of the grip recess has some more screws.

I pulled three more screws from there and the door panel removed easily.  I don't know if this model is unusual, but none of the guides I was using mentioned screws in that area.